# Is there a hormone combination that makes humans grumpy?

Tags: human-biology, brain, endocrinology, behaviour

Imagine a typical situation that is likely to give rise to a bad temper within an individual: a person is awoken very early in the morning by a sound of a lawn being mowed next door.

Unlike expected awakening by an alarm clock, such unexpected awakening by a lawn mower is likely to leave the person in a bad temper, feeling grumpy or sulky.

**I'm interested if there's a specific hormone or process that makes a person experience the feeling of grumpiness?** Is it related to adrenaline and fight or flight instinct?

In other words, can experience of grumpiness be induced under laboratory conditions by using some combination of hormones/drugs?

Comment: I don't think morning grumpiness is related to adrenaline or fight/flight. It's more a matter of being irritated by the discomfort of abrupt awakening (at an inappropriate phase of sleep). "Grumpiness" per se is also poorly defined; for *anger* I am sure adrenaline and (if male) testosterone is often high, but I doubt just these hormones by themselves can induce anger (although they could make someone more prone to fits of anger).

Comment: I've seen anecdotal evidence suggesting that "low dopamine" contributes to irritability

Comment: I live in an apartment complex of 20 buildings. They used to send a huge loud truck around to empty the giant trash dumpsters, every Thursday at 4 am. It sounded like a war for about 20 minutes. I finally complained and they moved to 8 am. They still come around early once in a while though. I usually felt "grumpy" due to that! Who wouldn't? A completely stupid policy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a hard question to respond to.

Many things might make someone grumpy.  There are also individual temperaments, making grumpy hard to quantify - a Grumpy to one person might barely be a blip on another individual's scale.  Hormones like cortisol reflect stress, and can make people in general irritable, but I doubt any one combination of hormones would always cause grumpiness.

But I thought I'd venture an answer since I did see this paper today:  ["Low glucose relates to greater aggression in married couples"](http://www.pnas.org/content/111/17/6254.short?rss=1&ssource=mfr) doi: 10.1073/pnas.1400619111

Being hungry will do this for lots of people, so maybe a bit of an answer for you. There are lots of different kinds of signals that mediate hunger though, so still a tough call.

Update: here's an additional article that specifically talks about [parts of the brain involved in aggression and grumpiness as response to a drop in glucose](http://www.iflscience.com/health-and-medicine/science-hangry-or-why-some-people-get-grumpy-when-they-re-hungry).